# Execution has failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android

I'm trying to produce an app which opens multiple activities etc. and this error keeps appearing. After looking through all possible suggestion none have work. Here's the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat
> >     --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Jason\AndroidStudioProjects\SaintBedes\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
> >     --input-list=C:\Users\Jason\AndroidStudioProjects\SaintBedes\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
> >     Error Code:   1

Here's the Build.gradle (Project)

> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
>   to all sub-projects/modules.

```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
> 
>         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>         // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     } 
> }

> 
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     } }
```

Here's the Build.gradle (Module:App):

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> 
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 21
>     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "saintbedeslytham.saintbedes"
>         minSdkVersion 15
>         targetSdkVersion 21
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>     sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/layout-land'] } } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your sdk and check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of your libraries isn't compiling. Try removing them `build.gradle`  and adding them one by one to see which one is causing problems.